# Netbeans 8.2 uninstall in Windows 10

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, netbeans-8

I have tried to uninstall Netbeans from control panel, but when I try to remove it, this pops out "JDK not found on your computer" https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF74Z.jpg , but Netbeans is working perfectly, my JAVA_HOME and Path have the right paths. I tried to launch the installer, maybe it would change the "uninstall.exe", but it didn't do anything. When I execute uninstall.exe, it doesn't create a log file in .nbi/log, I have there just the installation and logs for the times I tried to reinstall in hope for "repair"

Comment: On Windows 10 NetBeans will have created a log file for your uninstall in folder **C:\Users\{your user ID}\.nbi\log**. The name of that log file will be similar to **20180304230856.log** but based on the actual date/time of your NetBeans uninstall. Have a look in that file to see if there is any helpful information and update your post accordingly.

Comment: I have 3 log files in there, one seems to correspond to the installation script, and two identical ones for the time I tried to "repair" Netbeans running the installer all over again. It doesn't seem to have the uninstallation one. The other ones in there don't tick something for me

Comment: If you can't locate the uninstall log could you try uninstalling again if that is still possible. A log file should definitely be created. Its first line should look similar to this _"[2018-03-04 23:08:56.208]: entering -- org.netbeans.installer.Installer.main():81"_

Comment: It doesn't create one, I removed all the log files from the folder and then execute the uninstaller but it didn't create one